# View desktop from mobile using a switch

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, content-management-system, mootools

I am trying to embed a 'Desktop View' link into my mobile webpage then a 'Mobile view' link on the desktop link if the user wishes to reverse their decision.

So far I have been able to successfully add the javascript to ignore/bypass the CSS that would style the page in either desktop or mobile view depending on which link you click but the problem I am having is that the cookie is being set when the user first selects 'Desktop View' but not being retained. I'm using a boolean to check to see if the cookie is present and if it isnt then it's supposed to create the cookie. I have set up Console.Log to show when certain aspects are functioning and it appears that the check to see if the cookie is already present is being overlooked, its just setting a new one everytime which is having a diverse effect on the way the user navigates the webpage.

```
window.addEvent('domready', function () {
  if ($('FooterDesktopView')){

    console.log("desktopagain");

    var windowcookie = getCookie('NonResponsiveVersion');               
    if (windowcookie == true){                                         

      removejscssfile("//static.uk-plc.net/library-cms/abd/bab95b16-20ba-4090-b883-1bee04bc58fc.css", "css");
      $$('.remove-css').addClass('displaynone');
      $$('.load-css').removeClass('displaynone');

    } 
    else {

      $$('.remove-css').each(function (el) {
        el.addEvent('click', function () {

          console.log("desktop");

          removejscssfile("//static.uk-plc.net/library-cms/abd/bab95b16-20ba-4090-b883-1bee04bc58fc.css", "css");
          $$('.remove-css').addClass('displaynone');
          $$('.load-css').removeClass('displaynone');

          setCookie('NonResponsiveVersion', 'desktop', '1'); 
        });
      }); 
    }
  } 
});
```

Using the Colnsole.log i'm finding that this section is being overlooked

```
console.log("desktopagain");

var windowcookie = getCookie('NonResponsiveVersion');
if (windowcookie == true){

  removejscssfile("//static.uk-plc.net/library-cms/abd/bab95b16-20ba-4090-b883-1bee04bc58fc.css", "css");
  $$('.remove-css').addClass('displaynone');
  $$('.load-css').removeClass('displaynone');

} 
else {
```

Can anybody help me resolve this problem?

Comment: Yep you got it, need more information about the desktop and mobile versions and an example of how you are trying to do it please

Comment: ive set the screen sizes using CSS and the built in CMS JS writes itself rather than having to hard code it, ive not specified any mobile/desktops specifically only the screen sizes.

Comment: HTML.... <p><a document.location="http://preview.uk-plc.net/test-marketplace/index.html" href="#">LINK</a></p>

Comment: JS...  window.addEvent('domready', function() {
  <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    if (screen.width <= 700 && getCookie("mobileRedirected")!="true"){
setCookie('mobileRedirected','true',100);
    window.location = "http://preview.uk-plc.net/test-marketplace/index.html";
    }
    //-->
    </script>

Comment: Im going to post another question with this JS example im using as this comment boxes are to small!

Comment: I have asked the same question again with some of my most recent JS example

Answer (score 0):

It's about having different stylesheets. One for the very dynamic view (mobile view) and less dynamic as the desktop version. A simple link would do. For example, you would include a variable in your href.

```
<a href="?stylesheet=desktop">Desktop view</a>
```

Then, on the server side, you could have a script handle which set of stylesheets to link to.

If you don't want the GET-variables in the URL (for better linking to friends for example), you could do with a form.

```
<form method="POST" action="">
    <button type="submit" name="stylesheet" value="desktop">Switch to desktop</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I thought the same at the start but the screen sizes are set and it automatically recognises that its being viewed on at 319x480 screen (mobile) and wont ignore the JS that was written in the background.

Comment: I have asked the same question again with some of my most recent JS example

Answer (score -1):

The best option is to look and read carefully your CMS documentation (or use another CMS that support the feature) if you are not good at programing

Comment: Its the CMS we use at work, I'm new to programming and much prefer design but my boss has giving me this task. The CMS doesn't appear to have any option to ignore the mobile css and use the desktop css when selected by the mobile user